# frame_change handler called on mouse press and release event when scrubbing

Tags: python, scripting, timeline, mouse

```py
import bpy

def on_frame_change(scene):
    print("frame changed", scene.frame_current)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(on_frame_change)
```

After running the code above, each time I select a frame in the playback window a message will be printed containing the current frame number.

The problem I'm having is that clicking on a frame with my mouse in the playback window will trigger this handler twice. It will be triggered once for the mouse down event and it will trigger a second time for the mouse up event.

If I change frames using keyboard arrows or if the animation is playing then this handler is correctly only called one time per frame.

The only solution I can think of for this is to listen for mouse events and only run my handler code on the mouse down event but that seems hacky. Surely I'm just doing something wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender's Python API is currently very limited, but will hopefully incorporate more event handling capabilities. As a workaround you could try to implement a [Finite-State Automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) of mouse events. To give you an idea here is a simple handler that will detect mouse press, release, scrubbing/dragging, and scrub release events which you can see in the print statements.

[image]

```
import bpy

class FrameMouseHandler:
    def __init__(s):
        s.LMB_STATE_NONE = 0
        s.LMB_STATE_PRESS = 1
        s.LMB_STATE_RELEASE = 2
        s.LMB_STATE_DRAG = 3
        s.LMB_STATE_DRAG_RELEASE = 4
        s.frame = -1
        s.state = s.LMB_STATE_NONE

    def frame_get(s):
        return s.frame

    def update_frame(s):
        s.frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

    def update_state(s, state):
        s.state = state

    def update_handler(s, handler):
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(handler)

    def reset(s):
        s.update_handler(s.on_frame_press)
        s.update_state(s.LMB_STATE_NONE)

    def on_frame_change(s, scene, depsgraph):
        prev_frame = s.frame_get()
        s.update_frame()
        if prev_frame == s.frame_get():
            if s.state == s.LMB_STATE_DRAG:
                print("Mouse stop scrubbing and release on frame:", s.frame_get())
            else:
                print("Mouse released on frame:", s.frame_get())
            s.reset()
        else:
            print("Mouse scrubbing, currently at frame:", s.frame)
            s.update_state(s.LMB_STATE_DRAG)

    def on_frame_press(s, scene, depsgraph):
        s.update_frame()
        print("Mouse pressed on frame:", s.frame_get())
        s.update_handler(s.on_frame_change)
        s.update_state(s.LMB_STATE_PRESS)

        
handler = FrameMouseHandler()
handler.reset()
```

Take note that you still have to add more functionality to cater to the other timeline buttons as this script will go out of sync if you press timeline buttons such as:

```
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
bpy.ops.screen.frame_jump()
bpy.ops.screen.keyframe_jump()
```

Comment: So a couple things to note here. It would be best to rename the `s` parameter to `self` to keep with python convention. Also where did you find the documentation that describes the parameters passed to handlers? I see you added the `scene` and `depsgraph` parameters but I can't find anywhere they defines the handler function prototypes. It clearly works and removing them raises an error that 3 parameters were expected.


I also wonder if there is a way of implementing this by subclassing their base handler class.

Comment: @BlenderRookie i don't like the self thing, it makes my code lines too long and hard to read, especially if you have more than 1 member variable or function call in one line. that is my preference :) i think blender is poorly documented, i found out the types by adding several arguments and printing out their `type(arg)`, that's how i know :)

Comment: Yeah haha I've been doing a lot of `dir(<function>)` to figure out how their API is set up. The documentation is certainly lacking.