# How to detect if user is scrubbing through frames?

Tags: python, scripting

Blender provides an `is_scrubbing` property as shown [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Screen.html#bpy.types.Screen.is_scrubbing) however I am struggling to actually detect when the user is scrubbing through frames while playback is disabled.

```py
import bpy

def on_frame_change(scene):
    screen = bpy.context.screen
    if not screen.is_animation_playing and screen.is_scrubbing:
        print("scrubbing")
    elif screen.is_animation_playing and not screen.is_scrubbing:
        print("animation playing")
    else:
        print("neither?", screen.is_animation_playing, screen.is_scrubbing)

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(on_frame_change)
```

What I would expect is that when the user manually selects a frame in the playback window, this would result in `is_animation_playing=False` and `is_scrubbing=True`. However, when a frame is manually selected, `is_animation_playing` is actually `True`.

The only solution I can think of for this is to register `animation_playback_pre` and `animation_playback_post` handlers to register a flag like `is_playing` then use that from within my `frame_change` as shown below:

```py
import bpy

def on_playback_start(scene):
    scene.collection["is_playing"] = True

def on_playback_stop(scene):
    scene.collection["is_playing"] = False

def on_frame_change(scene):
    if not scene.collection["is_playing"] and bpy.context.screen.is_scrubbing:
        print("scrubbing")
    elif scene.collection["is_playing"] and not bpy.context.screen.is_scrubbing:
        print("animation playing")
    else:
        print("neither?", scene.collection["is_playing"], bpy.context.screen.is_scrubbing)

bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.clear()
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()

bpy.context.scene.collection["is_playing"] = False
bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_pre.append(on_playback_start)
bpy.app.handlers.animation_playback_post.append(on_playback_stop)
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(on_frame_change)
```

Another problem with this approach is that using the arrow keys to manually change frames does not set `is_scrubbing` to `True` for some reason. So at this point it almost feels like I should just rely entirely on my custom `is_playing` variable to determine whether we are scrubbing and completely forget about Blender's built in `is_scrubbing` variable.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a better method to determine whether the user is manually scrubbing through frames?

Comment: Here answers the scrubbing problem? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299995/frame-change-handlers-called-on-mouse-event-press-and-release-when-scrubbing/300034#300034

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie that does solve the problem but I'd like to see if anyone has a more elegant solution. Might just be a limitation of the API at the moment, however.

Comment: yes it is a limitation unfortunately thus the workaround